# How to collapse several string to one by key?

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

For example I have a file:

```
key1   1212
key2   1212
key1   32332
key2   3232
key2   3232
```

I want to get file:

```
key1   1212,32332
key2   1212,3232,3232
```

Comment: this should be possible in bash, but I would suggest instead of breaking your brain - use better tools, if you ask bash - it's linux - definitely has python - use it - and task becomes simple.

Comment: Added awk and python tags due to comments on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]==""?"":",")$2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
key1 1212,32332
key2 1212,3232,3232
```

Explained:

```
awk '{                                        # use awk for this kind of stuff
    a[$1]=a[$1] ( a[$1]=="" ? "" : "," ) $2   # hash on first col and append seconds
}
END {                                         # after everything is hashed
    for(i in a)                               # for each entry in hash a
        print i,a[i]                          # output key and data
}' file                                       # oh yeah the file
```

**Edit:** Instead of having awk do the buffering (ie. hashing to `a`) we could use `sort` to sort the file and then output the key and all data after that comma-separated. Again using awk for the latter part:

```
$ sort file | awk '$1!=p{printf "%s%s",(NR>1?ORS:""),$1}{printf "%s%s", ($1==p?",":OFS),$2;p=$1}END{print ""}'
key1 1212,32332
key2 1212,3232,3232
```

Here `sort` is not given any fancy parameters but in the real world some could be required. The awk part explained:

```
sort file | \                          # sort the file
awk '                                  # before feeding to awk
$1!=p {                                # if key is different from previous key
    printf "%s%s",(NR>1?ORS:""),$1     # newline and print the key
}
{
    printf "%s%s", ($1==p?",":OFS),$2  # print the data comma-separated 
    p=$1                               # store key for comparing on the next round
}
END{ 
    print ""                           # finish the last line nicely
}'
```

Comment: answer most probably is good and working, but I always try too keep people away from parsing text files with bash - it's inefficient. and you don't know how big that input file is, so it can be really bad :), and Bdfy, taking into account your SO reputation - if you add tag python to your question I will provide working python solution, that I think is better to be used than bash.

Comment: @Drako : Having said that, `awk` is perfectly fine for small files

Comment: @sjsam I agree, but if input will be 500MB or more you will really be more happy with python solution :) that's why even for small I tend to use correct tools if possible, because you never know when it may grow :)

Comment: @Drako Added another awk version that relies on sorted input. BTW, I don't see how awk would consume any more resources than Python solution. I'll add the awk and python tags to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid buffering the results for the whole file (e.g. if the file is very large) you could use `sort` and Python's [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Create a Python script like this:

```
# group.py

import itertools, sys

for k, g in itertools.groupby(sys.stdin, lambda x: x.split()[0]):
    print(k, ",".join([x.split()[1] for x in g]))
```

Then run:

```
sort file | python group.py 
key1 1212,32332
key2 1212,3232,3232
```

Otherwise, this quick Perl one-liner should work as well by accumulating values in a hash:

```
perl -aE 'push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[1]; END {$"= ","; say "$_ @{$h{$_}}" for sort keys %h}' file
```

Output:

```
key1 1212,32332
key2 1212,3232,3232
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[$1]=(a[$1]!="")?a[$1]","$2:$2}END{for(i in a){print i "\t" a[i]}}' file
key1    1212,32332
key2    1212,3232,3232
```

should do it.

Answer (score -1):

it's not pure sh/coreutils, but consider using [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) for this task:

```
sed -r -e 's/[[:space:]]+/ /g' < infile.txt | datamash -t ' ' -s groupby 1 collapse 2
```